# How do I restart an Azure container group after the image has changed?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I am stuck with one last part of my Azure continuous deployment workflow.

The workflow looks like this:
 - Push to the gitbhub repository on a certain branch
 - This triggers a travis build which creates a docker image and uploads that image to Azure container registries
 - Container registries has a webhook that triggers the execution of a Logic App
 - In the Logic App, the only step is to create a container group, respectively update the existing container group. The step is called officially "Create container group". There I configure everything related to the container group like the network and environment variables.

That all works fine. I can also see in the logs of the Container instances the following entry at the end of the workflow "Create or update Container Group".

The problem is however that the container group does not get restarted after that. So the new container is not running. When I restart the container group manually, the new container will run.
And also if I execute the logic app after changing something in the container group like an environment variable, the container group gets restarted.

So my question is: How can I automatise the restart of the container group after it was updated with a new container image?

Comment: Do you use the Azure container instance in the Logic App?

Comment: @CharlesXu Yes, in the Logic App, I have a step called "Create container group"

Comment: Please show more information about  "Create or update Container Group", cause the container doesn't support update so what you could do is delete the old one and create a new. Also could show your workflow picture.